# Looking for a bitwise operator

Tags: java, c++, c, bitwise-operators

I have a list of objects of the same class. The order of the list is not important.
What i want to do, is to (using bitwise operations) determine whether i should set some field with an incremental value or not. But the trick is that i <strike>want</strike> need this operation to return false (must not set field) only for the first element.

```
for (Obj obj:list){

 if (obj.isZero() (op) some_flag){
   //set field
 }
}
```

Here are some things that im certain of.

When called on the first element of the list, isZero() will return true.

When called on the rest of the elements, its uncertain. But if called on the second element, isZero() returns true, then it will return true for all the list  ([3..last])

Any way of doing this? I dont feel like keeping a counter and incrementing it, but if its **THE BEST PRACTICE** to do so, then ill do it.

Comment: I'm not sure 'bitwise' is the word you're looking for. I think you looking for more of a 'logical' operator. Bitwise would be like doing an AND on two integers, ANDing each bit "bitwise".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a counter

Comment: going with it, im in a rush.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `isZero` isn't guaranteed to return `true` for elements after the first, then you cannot use it to detect whether an element is not the first element without remembering that there was an occurence of the first element already. So what you ask cannot be done.

You don't need a counter there, though -  a simple `boolean isFirst = true`, reset to `false` on the first iteration, will do the trick just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a count of all the elements that return (obj.isZero() (op) some_flag), and all elements after that element will continue to return true after that, then something like the following will work:

```
int counter = 0;

for (Obj obj : list) {
    if (obj.isZero() (op) some_flag) {
        counter = list.size() - list.indexOf(obj);
        break;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you are not guaranteed that the following elements will be true *unless* it is the second element, then I would just use a simple counter:

```
int counter = 0;

for (Obj obj : list) {
    if (obj.isZero() (op) some_flag) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a boolean will do, won't it?

```
boolean notFirst = false;
for (Obj obj : list) {
  if (notFirst) {
    ...
  } else {
    notFirst = true;
  }
}
```